# Compile artifact in IntelliJ IDEA with dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to compile an artifact with dependecies of commons-io (org.apache.commons.io), IDE included it in maven automatically.

Thing is, I prefer compiling artifacts over compiling maven projects. And when I compile artifacts, I get `NoClassDefFoundError`, but when I compile project with maven, everything works. What should I do to make artifacts have those dependencies?

PS: my artifact settings.
[image]

Comment: Are you creating a plugin for spigot?

Comment: Yes, I have main plugin of bungeecord and spigot one for commands-helpers. @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

Just deleted the old artifact and created new one, and it worked.